# Angular 2: Subscribe once in MainComponent for all routes

Tags: angular

I have ProjectModule. Every page in this module requires the `projectService.projectData` property before loading.

**ProjectComponent**

```
ngOnInit() {
this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
    let name = params['name'];
    if (name) {
      this.projectService.getProject(name);
  }
  });
});
  }
```

**ProjectService**

```
getProject(name) {
    //Friendly URL to ID
    this.af.database.object('/friendly_urls/' + name).take(1).subscribe((data) => {
      //ID to data
      this.af.database.object('/projects/' + data.$value).take(1).subscribe((projectData) => {
        this.projectData = projectData;
      });
    },
    error =>  {
      console.log(error);
      /* TODO: Permission blocked page */
      this.router.navigate(['']);
    });
  }
```

I have to make `getProject(name)` method in each component to get the project data.

How I can make sure I get the `projectData` from the service before accessing any route?

Is it possible to achieve it without `subscribe` to service in each component `ngOnInit`?

Comment: You are already storing the data in the `projectData` property of the service.  Just access that property in your components.  i.e: `export class SomeComponent { constructor(projectService: ProjectService) { }`  then in any method in the component that needs the data, just `this.projectService.projectData`.  If you fire the `getProject` method early in the load process, the data will be sitting there available to the app.  Just make sure you aren't declaring the `ProjectService` in *every* module's `providers` array, just in the main module, so you are working with the singleton service.

Comment: Yes I store it in `projectData`. but when I'm trying to use projectData in one of my components, I get that `projectData` is undefined. What I'm asking is how I can avoid make a subscription in each component

Comment: Are you including the ProjectService in each module's providers? or just in the highest module file (`app.module` maybe?).  If you have it in the `app.module` and then in a lower module, say `project.module`, then you are creating a new instance of the service in each module.

Comment: I have it only in my higher module (ProjectModule). Let's say your refreshing the page at `/projects/my-project/users`. the `ngOnInit()` method in my question is executed, and there is no enough time until I receive the data until the `ProjectUserComponent` `ngOnInit()` method is executing with the `projectData`.

Comment: If you are calling `getProject()` once in the `ProjectComponent`, then you shouldn't need to call it again in the `ProjectUserComponent`.  Just have the `ProjectUserComponent` reference the `projectData` property of the service.  You can have it handle it being `null`/`undefined` until the data comes back with an `*ngIf` or the `?` operator like `{{projectData?}}`

Comment: I can't handle it because I'm using the data in my `ProjectUserComponent` ngOnInit() and not in the template. I tried to place if (projectService.proejctData) in my component init but then it's not executing at all. That means in each component I have to get the route params again, subscribe until I get the `projectData` :(

Comment: Could you just move the logic to a higher level and pass in the data you need as it's available?  i.e move the logic out of the `ProjectUserComponent` into the `ProjectComponent`, let it handle working out all the details from the service call, and only pass in the data you actually need in the user component?

Comment: If I understood correctly, that means my `getProject()` service method will have 20+ subscriptions and will load the data for all my project compnents in one time? It think it's way too much data in one time..

Comment: I mean, I don't know what the data looks like that you are getting through your service.  But if you get the data once, there's no need to get the data again.

Comment: The point is good. I wish I could, but most of the data is real time and it won't work well subscribing to tens of observables in one time